# calculation error vb.net textbox

Tags: vb.net

I am working with inventory system, Transaction form I had mainly 2 text box, first 1 is avaqty its from database available qty, other textbox is avqty from user adding qty.

When user add qty avaqty textbox automatically change to 
(avaqty) -(avqty) but as an example 10-10 result come in -1

My code is:

```
Public Class transaction
Dim objcon As New connectionclass

Dim qty As String
Public Function getqty() As String
    If itemid.Text = "" Then
    Else
        Try
            objcon.myconnection.Open()
            Dim getqty1 As New OleDbCommand("select balance from avaqty where item_id=" & itemid.Text & "", objcon.myconnection)
            Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = getqty1.ExecuteReader
            While reader.Read
                qty = reader("balance")
            End While
            objcon.myconnection.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End If
    Return qty
End Function
Private Sub itemid_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles itemid.KeyPress
    If Asc(e.KeyChar) = 13 Then
        objcon.myconnection.Open()
        Try

            Dim getdata As New OleDbCommand("select*from itemtbl where item_id=" & itemid.Text & "", objcon.myconnection)
            Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = getdata.ExecuteReader
            While reader.Read

                itemdesc.Text = reader("item_des").ToString
                yom.Text = reader("unit_of_mesure").ToString
                cost.Text = reader("item_cost").ToString

            End While

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
        objcon.myconnection.Close()
    End If
    If getqty() = 0 Then
        avaqty.Text = 0
    Else
        avaqty.Text = getqty()
    End If
End Sub



Private Sub initem_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles initem.CheckedChanged
    dataview.DataSource = GETDATA()
End Sub

Private Sub outitem_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles outitem.CheckedChanged
    dataview.DataSource = GETDATA2()
End Sub

Private Sub avqty_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles avqty.TextChanged
    Try
        If avqty.Text = "" Then
            avaqty.Text = getqty()
        Else

            avaqty.Text = CDbl(avaqty.Text - avqty.Text)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub avaqty_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles avaqty.TextChanged
    If avaqty.Text < 0 Then
        MsgBox("not inough qty")
        avqty.Clear()
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: This looks like a debugging issue which we will struggle to help with. What I will advise is, use **SQL parameters** and turn **Option Strict On**. I would also implement `Using`.

Comment: As well as using @Bugs suggestion, I'd use `MessageBox.Show` rather than `MsgBox`. It's the newer and, in my opinion, better version on message boxes in `vb.net`

Comment: There seems to be a couple of issues with your code.. getqty() returns a string and not an integer you might want to edit it so that it returns an integer. Also the If statement at the end of your keypress event will execute every time a key of any kind is pressed - This doesn't seem right. Solving these two issues might help a little as they remove potential bugs.

Comment: i was try but its not working  as a example  ava qty =10  out qty =10 so answer should be 0.but its showing -1.